# Fetch multiple rows of other database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to optimize some data retrieval. There are several tables of data related to the members table. There are many other examples of this multi-level data retrieval, but this is the simplest.

To show the type of array I'm trying to build, this is how I would achieve it in PHP

```
$memberID = 1;
$memberData = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='.$memberID)->Fetch();
$memberData['events'] = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM events WHERE participant='.$memberID)->FetchAll();
$memberData['teams'] = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM teams WHERE member='.$memberID)->FetchAll();
$memberData['photos'] = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM photos WHERE member='.$memberID)->FetchAll();
$memberData['videos'] = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE member='.$memberID)->FetchAll();
```

This results an array like this:

```
Array(
    'username'=>'JohnDoe',
    'email'=>'johndoe@google.com',
    'address'=>'Hollywood, CA',
    'events'=>Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            'id'=>7,
            'prize'=>'$1,000',
            'participant'=>1,
            'starting_date'=>'May 23, 2017'
        ),
        [1]=>Array(
            'id'=>9,
            'prize'=>'$3,000',
            'participant'=>1,
            'starting_date'=>'June 14, 2016'
        )
    ),
    'teams'=>Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            'id'=>2,
            'name'=>'LA Riots',
            'member'=>1
        ),
        [1]=>Array(
            'id'=>5,
            'name'=>'Queen City Kings',
            'member'=>1
        )
    ),
    'photos'=>Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            'id'=>2,
            'src'=>'photo2.png',
            'member'=>1
        ),
        [1]=>Array(
            'id'=>5,
            'src'=>'photo5.png',
            'member'=>1
        )
    ),
    'videos'=>Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            'id'=>2,
            'src'=>'youtu.be/a4J2KL4as',
            'member'=>1
        ),
        [1]=>Array(
            'id'=>5,
            'src'=>'youtu.be/Bg82JL0DSZ',
            'member'=>1
        )
    )
)
```

I'm trying to find a way to do this on the fly with a variable amount of tables, and, again, store all the data in one multidimensional array.

Is this possible with querying?